# What is a respectful way to say "homosexual (man)"?

Tags: word-choice

Last night, I wanted to tell a Japanese person that a famous singer was homosexual. And, I wanted to say it in a respectful way. The only words I knew were オカマ and ホモ. Both make me cringe. It sounds like derogatory / harsh slang???

Now, she didn't think オカマ sounded bad, but... she is from Shikoku, Japan's analog to Alabama? In Tokyo, オカマ is not acceptable, right?

Anyway, in a daily conversation with educated adults, what is a way to say "homosexual" that is no different in connotation than saying someone is "tall", "smart", "creative", etc?

btw: We were talking about Queen's performance for LIVE AID 30 years ago this week in Wembley Stadium. Every critic agrees that was the best live performance, *ever*. It's on youtube to see.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the most neutral term for a third-person is 同性愛者{どうせいあいしゃ}.

If you're looking for a little less formal-sounding word ゲイ or ホモセクシュアル will also convey the idea.

http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%90%8C%E6%80%A7%E6%84%9B%E8%80%85

Comment: Using 四字熟語 sounds a little stilted for describing a human being in a daily conversation. 同性愛者 sounds to me like a word you'd use in an academic article. (Of course, if you are native speaker then my feeling about 同性愛者 is null and void.)

Comment: 同性愛者 isn't really a 四字熟語, although I understand your point. It's a combination of 同性愛 (homosexuality) and 者 (person). It's used in newspaper articles and on the news. It's not strictly academic, just neutral and specific.

Comment: I guess what I mean is saying 4 音読み sounds in a row to describe a person in daily conversation sounds stiff. Kind of like rather than describing his character, you are assigning a strict definition. I thought there be a softer sounding word.

Comment: I think「同性愛者」doesn't sound any stiffer than "homosexual" in this context. They are essentially equivalent.

Comment: I've done a lot of reading about LGBT issues in japan, and I agree with sazarando that the tone of 同性愛者 and "homosexual" are equal. Most gay people would call themselves "gay" before "homosexual" and I think the same is for Japan. I've seen ゲイand ホモ used more often than 同性愛(者) in articles and interview videos on youtube.

Answer (score 0):

They use ニューハーフ (new-half) here all the time for men that act like women, not sure if it works the other way around. I also hear ゲイの人 a lot.

Comment: Nope. ニューハーフ (new-half) is used almost exclusively for transsexuals and those who have had or will have a sex change operation.